# Status of the Bressan conjecture

Tags: linear-pde, bounded-variation

Let me first recall what is the Bressan conjecture. Take a $BV\cap L^\infty$ vector field $X$ on some open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ such that there exists an $L^\infty$ function $\alpha\ge 1$ so that
$
\text{div}(\alpha X)=0
$
(such a vector field is said to be nearly incompressible). Let $\Sigma$ be a $C^1$ hypersurface non-characteristic with respect to $X$. Then the weak $L^\infty$ solutions of the equation
$$
Xu=0, \quad u_{\vert \Sigma}=0,
$$
are vanishing near $\Sigma$. In short that conjecture claims that the weak solutions of the Cauchy problem for  a nearly incompressible $BV$ vector field are unique. The original version of the conjecture was dealing with compactness of the flows of approximations of a nearly incompressible vector field but anyhow this was proven equivalent to the previous uniqueness statement.

I heard a couple of years ago that the conjecture had been proven, but I have not seen any published article appearing in a Journal. So my question is "What is the status of the Bressan conjecture?"

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my query is in fact the following: Bressan's conjecture was proven in 2020 in a paper authored by Stefano Bianchini & Paolo Bonicatto, published by Invent. math. (2020) 220:255–393, "A uniqueness result for the decomposition of vector fields in $\mathbb R^d$."